# Implement a Class tuple into the methods of the Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want to find out how do I implement the class tuple 'excludedWords' in the methods so that the methods will ignore them. I have tried to use the split method and tried calling the tuple whether it be self.excludedWords or Prose.excludedWords inside that split method.

```
class Prose:
    excludedWords = ('is', 'the', 'are', 'we', 'they', 'it', 'he', 'she')

    def __init__(self, words):
        self.prose = words

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.prose)

    def numberOfWords(self):
        return len(self.prose.split())

    def distinctWords(self):
        return len(self.prose.split(self.prose)) 

    def toString(self):
        for words in self.prose.split():
            print(words)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if self.prose != other.prose:
            newprose = self.prose.split(other.prose)
            otherprose = other.prose.split(self.prose)
            return newprose
        else:
            return self.prose 

    def newDict(self):
        myDict = {}
        myProse = self.prose.split()
        for word in myProse:
            if word in myDict:
               myDict[word] += 1
            else:
               myDict[word] = 1
        return myDict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, words):
    self.prose = words
    self.filtered_prose = ' '.join([w for w in words.split() if w not in excludedWords])
```

This will filter out any of the words you want to exclude in the beginning.
Note that if punctuation follows an excluded word like `"is,"`, it will not exclude that word.